# How to do data modeling when the model is partially initialized from DB?

Tags: design-patterns

Consider data modeling in Scala(the other language is the same), we often want to composite one model inside another, e.g a `Post` may contain an author field whose type is a `User`.

When we retrieve the data from db, we might want to retrieve some basic information due to the performance consideration and complete the others missing parts when it is needed.  The only way I can do is to make those fields as some `Option`s in model.

But this makes the model dirty in semantics and not convenient to use since those fields are actually mandatory in model. In the above case, every Post has an author, but I has no choice except to implement it as an Option.

Any advices on this?

Comment: The idea of a [null object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern): a `User` subclass has default, benign, neutral, etc. behavior. The client code won't know it's dealing with a mere shell of an object.

Comment: @radarbob It seems I need to provide `null object` for all the primitives to use this pattern. Is there any library already done this if it is true?

Comment: I've not heard of any such library. However [this book on refactoring](http://www.amazon.com/Refactoring-Improving-Design-Existing-Code/dp/0201485672) is where I first learn about it. A book worth actually buying IMOH.

Comment: The way you describe it, you working very state full. Instead I would recommend to use polymorphism to include bigger and more advance logic to different layers of the model. It's ofc also possible to `Lazy load` the author, but I'm sure you know that already and choose not to for performance reasons :)

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this using laziness.

```
scala> def fetchPost(id: Int): (Int, String) = { println("fetching content") ; val userId = 42; (userId, "content of post") }
fetchPost: (id: Int)(Int, String)

scala> def fetchUser(userId: Int): (String, String) = { println("fetching user"); ("firstname", "lastname") }
fetchUser: (userId: Int)(String, String)

scala> class Post(id: Int) {
    | lazy val (userId, content) = fetchPost(id)
    | lazy val user = fetchUser(userId)
    | }
defined class Post

scala> val post1 = new Post(1)
post1: Post = Post@2362f559

scala> post1.user
fetching content
fetching user
res0: (String, String) = (firstname,lastname)

scala> val post2 = new Post(2)
post2: Post = Post@17d919b6

scala> post2.content
fetching content
res1: String = content of post

scala> post2.user
fetching user
res2: (String, String) = (firstname,lastname)
```

The fetching is done on demand when needed. On the other hand, you shouldn't do these kinds of optimizations until you have performance data that explicitly tells you you have a problem. Especially if you can get your database to fetch all the data from different tables in one go, you might be micro-optimizing just to get worse performance in the end.

Comment: What if your `fetchUser` returns `Future[]` ?

Comment: Then it's a different question, and should be treated as such here too. In general, I'd say do the simple answer of loading first and then only after you have measurements to prove that you have a specific problem, then optimize. If your database layer returns Futures anyways, you can run the queries in parallel.